# Why is Hibernate making a select call with join when manually passing id?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, orm

In Student class, I am passing the id manually and all my entity-relationship are in LAZY mode.

But because I am passing the id, Spring DATA JPA (Hibernate) will treat as a merge request and make a SELECT call and will try to merge it. But I can not understand why it is trying to JOIN all relationships.

I was expecting select call for student table and not joining other tables. I can not understand why it is happening ?

```
    select
        student0_.uuid as uuid1_2_3_,
        student0_.address_uuid as address_3_2_3_,
        student0_.name as name2_2_3_,
        address1_.uuid as uuid1_0_0_,
        address1_.city_uuid as city_uui5_0_0_,
        address1_.lat as lat2_0_0_,
        address1_.lon as lon3_0_0_,
        address1_.pincode as pincode4_0_0_,
        city2_.uuid as uuid1_1_1_,
        city2_.name as name2_1_1_,
        subjects3_.student_uuid as student_4_3_5_,
        subjects3_.uuid as uuid1_3_5_,
        subjects3_.uuid as uuid1_3_2_,
        subjects3_.course_start_date as course_s2_3_2_,
        subjects3_.name as name3_3_2_,
        subjects3_.student_uuid as student_4_3_2_ 
    from
        student student0_ 
    inner join
        address address1_ 
            on student0_.address_uuid=address1_.uuid 
    left outer join
        city city2_ 
            on address1_.city_uuid=city2_.uuid 
    left outer join
        subject subjects3_ 
            on student0_.uuid=subjects3_.student_uuid 
    where
        student0_.uuid=?
```

```
@Entity
public class Student {

    @Id
    private UUID uuid;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
    private Address address;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Subject> subjects;
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Subject {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID uuid;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private ZonedDateTime courseStartDate;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Student student;
}
```

```
@Entity
public class City {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID uuid;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID uuid;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private City city;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String pincode;

    @Column
    private double lat;

    @Column
    private double lon;
}
```

```
Test Case :

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = NONE)
public class StudentRepositoryIT  {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Rollback(value = false)
    @Test
    public void should_fetch_student() {
        // GIVEN
        UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
        Student john = new Student().setName("John Wick").setUuid(uuid);
        City newyork = new City().setName("Newyork City");
        Address address = new Address().setCity(newyork)
                .setLat(12.3)
                .setLon(13.4)
                .setPincode("010101");
        john.setAddress(address);
        Subject maths = new Subject().setName("maths").setCourseStartDate(ZonedDateTime.now()).setStudent(john);
        Subject english = new Subject().setName("english").setCourseStartDate(ZonedDateTime.now()).setStudent(john);
        Subject hindi = new Subject().setName("hindi").setCourseStartDate(ZonedDateTime.now()).setStudent(john);
        Subject geology = new Subject().setName("geology").setCourseStartDate(ZonedDateTime.now()).setStudent(john);
        Subject physics = new Subject().setName("physics").setCourseStartDate(ZonedDateTime.now()).setStudent(john);
        Subject science = new Subject().setName("science").setCourseStartDate(ZonedDateTime.now()).setStudent(john);
        john.setSubjects(List.of(maths, english, hindi, geology, physics, science));
        studentRepository.saveAndFlush(john);
        TestTransaction.end();

        // WHEN
        TestTransaction.start();
        Student student = entityManager.find(Student.class, uuid);
        System.out.println(student);
        System.out.println(student.getAddress());
        Address address1 = student.getAddress();
        System.out.println(address1.getLat());


        // THEN
          check query console
    }
}
```

Entity Relationship diagram
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does so because you are using `CascadeType.ALL` which means that Hibernate should cascade also for the `merge` operation. In order to cascade, Hibernate must load the data first and instead of loading the data by doing individual selects, Hibernate uses joins.

Comment: I didn't know that CascadeType.ALL will affect the READ operation.

Comment: It doesn't affect the read operation of `EntityManager#find`, but it affects what Hibernate reads from the database when doing a merge.

Comment: because we were providing id manually and hibernate is going to take this a merge over persists this leads to this call.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about `City`, but for the others Hibernate needs the join to determine if the respective field is `null` or not, which it needs to know before returning your root entity.

Comment: ok, it makes sense but still won't be it cheap if it check only in root entity. But why it is joining city I can't make sense?